# Предикативы в многокомпонентном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

> Удивлённый Никифор продолжает рапортовать, что хозяйка, когда мы съезжали, нашей миски ему не отдала по той причине, что так как я её собственный горшок разбил, то она за свой горшок нашу миску удерживает, и что будто бы я ей это сам таким образом предложил.

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! Помогите, пожалуйста, разделить предложение на предикативные единицы и составить схему предложения. Безмерно благодарна!

Answer (score 2):

*[1.Удивлённый Никифор продолжает рапортовать], (2.что хозяйка,( 3.когда мы съезжали), нашей миски ему не отдала по той причине), (4.что (5.так как я её собственный горшок разбил),то она за свой горшок нашу миску удерживает), и (6.что будто бы я ей это сам таким образом предложил).*

6 предикативных единиц. Сложноподчинённое предложение с 5 придаточными предложениями с разной связью: 2 и 6 -однородная связь придаточных (*рапортовать, что хозяйка нашей миски не отдала и что будто бы я ей это сам таким образом предложил)*; 2, 3 и 4 - параллельное подчинение (*когда мы съезжали, хозяйка миски не отдала по той причине, что она за свой горшок нашу миску удерживает*);  2, 4,5 - последовательное подчинение (*не отдала по той причине, что она нашу миску удерживает, так как я её горшок разбил)*

Схема в тексте предложения.